# Внедрить многопоточность в программу

Tags: многопоточность, java

Есть вот такой класс, рекурсивно сканирует все директории начиная с каталога **path**
и пишет отчет о всех найденных файлах в файл **reportPath**

мне нужно внедрить многопоточность в эту программу, как лучше это сделать ?

```
public class FilesReport {

    private String path;
    private FileWriter wrt;

    public FilesReport(String path, String reportPath) throws IOException {
        this.path = path;
        this.wrt = new FileWriter(new File(reportPath));
    }

    public ArrayList<File> findFilesRecursive() throws IOException {
        return findFilesRecursive(path);
    }

    public ArrayList<File> findFilesRecursive(String path) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(path);
        ArrayList<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();

        if (!file.canRead()) {
            //return result;
        }

        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if (files == null) {
            return result;
        }

        sortFiles(files);

        for (File item : files) {
            if (item.isDirectory()) {
                result.addAll(findFilesRecursive(item.getPath()));
            } else {
                result.add(item);
                writeReport(item);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void writeReport(File item) throws IOException{
        String lastModified = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(new Date(item.lastModified()));

        String report = "[\n" +
                "file = "+item.getPath()+"\n" +
                "date = "+lastModified+"\n" +
                "size = "+item.length()+"]";

        wrt.append(report);
        wrt.flush();
    }

    private void sortFiles(File[] files) {
        Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return f1.getPath().compareTo(f2.getPath());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Что означает «внедрить многопоточность»? Это всё равно что «добавить переменных» или «использовать циклы». Какая ваша настоящая проблема?

Если необходимо просто для галочки, напишите `new Thread().Start().Join();`.

Answer (score 1):

я думаю можно было бы выделять новый поток на каждую ветку каталогов. надо будет следить за лог файлом

Comment: Если выделять новый поток на каждую ветку (для корневых каталогов стартовой директории)

скажем есть директории
C:\Windows\addins
C:\Windows\AppCompat
C:\Windows\AppPatch
....
и создаем на них потоки, по одному потоку на каждую директорию
но не более 20-30 потоков или сколько оптимальное количество потоков ? 

но как действовать если в корневой директории одна директория, а в ней уже много вложенных директорий ?

Comment: И как записывать информацию в лог, чтобы вывод был как сейчас упорядоченный по директориям с сортировкой по имени.
можно все положить в один ArrayList а потом отсортировать, но нужно не расходовать много памяти и писать в лог сразу и с небольшим буфером.